# Why has Outlook connect (2003) suddenly stopped reading my Microsoft email?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, connector

I use Outlook through Outlook Connect to manage my windows email. It has worked flawlessly for over 6 months.

Suddenly I have discovered that about 2 weeks ago, it stopped showing my new emails in Outlook.

When I go to the bottom of the window and select "Server Status", everything shows as connected, but the new messages are not in Outlook.

I can find no way to fix this. Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT: Outlook 2003

Comment: Have you tried recreating your Outlook profile? When you hit send receive does it show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found out why it suddenly stopped, but after much searching on the net I tried (3 times) to remove my Microsoft account and re-install it. For some reason, the 3rd time it worked.

Please, @Cole Lavallee, put your comment in an answer so I can accept it, as I believe that is what you were suggesting. Otherwise I'll have to accept my own answer.

I have up-voted your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just few days ago Microsoft turned on Exchange sync for all Hotmail/Windows Live email accounts so I suggest to try to sync like you'd do it with Microsoft Exchange and not ouse the Outlook Connector at all. More: http://www.redmondpie.com/hotmail-push-email-exchange-activesync/
I even use it on my own domain address.

Comment: Colour me dumb but I don't get it. This is a push application for iphone and I don't understand how it relates to my needs. Can you elucidate?

Regards,

Comment: Well that was my guess as for a reason of the problem, but maybe it is a different thing. It relates to you: now you don't have to use Outlook Connector for Windows LIve Mail (Hotmail). It mimics the Exchange now so sync your Outlook exactly like to an Exchange server.